# Display multiple results as a single row

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table of users, who each have their own email/username/password, etc.

I have a secondary table of additional emails, which a user can add onto their account. The only link between the two is a userID.

I'm trying update some report functionality to accurately display these additional emails, but I'd like them to all be on one line, with sequential column names. I have limited flexibility in this, and need to wrap the logic entirely in a select statement.

Currently I am pulling in the second emailS table using a Join, and grabbing the emailAddress column. However this results in multiple rows of the same user, with only the email address being different, I would prefer if they could be condensed to one row, with multiple columns.

Currently the table is set up as such:

UsersXEmails

```
USERID | EMAILADDRESSID | EMAILADDRESS
-------------------------------------------
 001           100        email1@test.com
 001           200        email2@test.com
 001           300        email3@test.com
 002           400        testing1@gmail.com
 002           500        testing2@gmail.com
 003           600        foobar@gmail.com
```

Is it possible to have my output in my report be:

```
USERNAME  | EMAIL   | ADDITIONALEMAIL1  | ADDITIONALEMAIL2 | ADDITIONALEMAIL3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob   | bob@bob.com |email1@test.com    |email2@test.com   | email3@test.com
Fred  | fred@fred   |testing1@gmail.com |testing2@gmail.com|             |
George| george@g.com|foobar@gmail.com   |                  |
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Azure Data Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me works with a item column, because I can control the size of the pivot dynamically generated. You can try the next code

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
    UserId INT,
    item INT,
    EmailAddressID INT,
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT '1', '1','1', 'email2@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '1', '2','2', 'email1@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '1', '3','3', 'email4@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '1', '4','4', 'email5@test.com'UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '1','5', 'email1@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '2','6', 'email2@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '3','7', 'email3@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '4','8', 'email4@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '5','9', 'email5@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '1','10', 'email1@test.com' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '2','11', 'email2@test.com' 

DECLARE @MaxItem INT

SELECT TOP 1 @MaxItem = UserId 
FROM
    (SELECT UserId, COUNT(1) AS cont 
     FROM #Table 
     GROUP BY UserId) a 
 GROUP BY 
     UserId
 ORDER BY 
     MAX(a.cont) DESC

 DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX);
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

 SET @columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(item)
                       FROM
                           (SELECT item 
                            FROM #Table 
                            WHERE UserId = @MaxItem) AS T
                       ORDER BY item
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

 --SELECT     *     FROM    (      SELECT  UserId, EmailAddress,EmailAddressID    FROM #Table    ) AS T    PIVOT       (    MAX(EmailAddress)    FOR EmailAddressID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])    ) AS P order by UserId;

 SET @sql = N'SELECT * 
              FROM
                  (SELECT  UserId, EmailAddress, item
                   FROM #Table) AS T
              PIVOT   
                  (MAX(EmailAddress) 
                       FOR item IN (' + @columns + N')) AS P 
              ORDER BY UserId;'; 

  -- select @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
DROP TABLE #Table;
```